# office-addin-sso with @azure/msal-browser

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-js, office-addins, azure-ad-msal, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to use **office-addin-sso** with **@azure/msal-browser** ?

I would like to:

- use *OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken()* to get the Identity Token.
- while at the same time use *@azure/msal-browser* as the fallback
  method.

I have managed to get both the above working and can successfully get the MS Graph access token using just @azure/msal-browser.

Given that we want to use msal-browser/auth code flow with PKCE (and not msal/implicit flow) for the fallback, what would be the most effective way of getting the **MS Graph access token** in this context.

and given that the office-addin-sso package uses **On Behalf Of Flow** (requiring a secret and redirect).

Any help/suggestions or guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `@azure/msal-browser` in the `office-addin-sso`. My addin is for a single domain and the users are supposed to be logged in on OneDrive so I expect to never need the login via the fallback. I get the token silently from msal and then pass it to MS graph to get an access token. This is the code that does it in the `ssoauthhelper.ts`:

```js
import * as Msal from '@azure/msal-browser';
export async function getToken_Email() {
  try {
    const msalConfig: Msal.Configuration = {
      auth: {
        clientId: "<your client id>", //This is your client ID
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>", //The <tenant> in the URL is the tenant ID of the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant (a GUID), or its tenant domain.
        redirectUri: "https://<your server>/office-js/fallbackauthdialog.html",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage", // Needed to avoid "User login is required" error.
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true, // Recommended to avoid certain IE/Edge issues.
      },
    };

    const msalInstance = new Msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    const silentRequest = {
      scopes: ["User.Read", "openid", "profile"]
    };
    let access_token: string;
    try {
      const loginResponse = await msalInstance.ssoSilent(silentRequest);
      access_token = loginResponse.accessToken;
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
        const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(silentRequest).catch(error => {
          // handle error
        });
      } else {
        // handle error
      }
    }

    console.log('silent token response: ' + JSON.stringify(access_token));


    // makeGraphApiCall makes an AJAX call to the MS Graph endpoint. Errors are caught
    // in the .fail callback of that call
    const graph_response: any = await makeGraphApiCall(access_token);
    console.log('graph response: ' + JSON.stringify(graph_response));
  } catch (exception) {
    console.log(exception);
  }
}

export async function makeGraphApiCall(accessToken: string): Promise < any > {
  try {
    const response = await $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo/",
      headers: {
        access_token: accessToken,
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken + ' '
      },
      cache: false,
    });
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error from Microsoft Graph. \n${err}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Its very helpful.

Is there any difference between these 2 approaches:

(1) Using @azure/msal-browser to get an Access Token [and then using this to access MS Graph]

or

(2) Using OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken() to get an Identity Token which can then be swapped for an Access Token [and then using this to access MS Graph]

What are the benefits/advantages of using (2) ?

Comment: I tried several different methods and the one in my answer was the only one that worked for me. I don't know if there is a difference between different methods.

Comment: Really Appreciate your help.

The Microsoft documentation is rather limited, especially when you want to step outside of "high-level quickstart" world of the Yeoman Generator.

Comment: You are welcome :-) Agree about the Yeoman Generator solutions, very limited and difficult to start from scratch. Took me months to figure out how to get the token silently. You can accept my answer as an answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: I don't really see the usage of the Onbehalf flow with OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken(). This is the standard PKCE flow and not using the sso token from the Office host.

Comment: Hi @NincaTirtil, I appreciate your answer. I am still puzzled with some parts. 1) Am I right that your code does _not_ run inside the office dialog window as you assume the users are logged in and will never need to redirect to the MS Identity Server? to ask consent? 2) Your error handler calls  msalInstance.loginPopup(), can this be used in an Office-Addin? I understood that we must always use the Office.Dialog? Can this popup  work in office on the web environment? 3) What is the file "ssoauthhelper.ts" that you refer to?  4) do you not use  OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken()? Thanks

Comment: @JimbobTheSailor hi! I have not worked with this recently, but I will try to answer some of your questions. 1) My add in works only in an office excel sheet on the web. You have to be logged in in order to access the sheet and the add-in. So I figured I don't need a fall back or anything for the login. 2) Because of my explanation in 1) I don't think my code will ever need the error handling so I have never reached that part of the code. But this code is supposed to work for web office, yes. 3) I will check and find where this is located 4) As far as I remember I couldn't get that to work.